# Learn multiples languages at the same time

Tags: multilingual

Any one can give some tips or ways to learn more than 2 programing languages, without getting confused?

im still learning python, bash and php.

thank you so much.

Comment: We don't know what's confusing you.  Do you have a specific example of something that isn't clear or doesn't make sense to you?  Perhaps an example of code which is behaving in an unexpected way?

Comment: I mean, I am often confused with the code structure, the way variables are declared, arrays, etc ...

also with some functions and libraries and many other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning more than one language is not too hard (it is called language polyglot).
You need to focus on the common ideas that are shared by languages. And they are:

- paradigms (very important, since many paradigms are shared)
- syntax (C type or not)
- use cases (web, desktop, mobile...)

The hard part is learning the language ecosystem and environment, good and bad parts, criticism, frameworks, tools... For this you need years to master.

Comment: mmm, ok thank for the tip. I was overwhelmed by having to learn everything quickly.

Comment: @Lordki please accept the answer if you find it useful. Thank you.